# MarkLogic dateTime using SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, marklogic

I am currently trying to get a ODBC Connection with a Postgresql Driver underneath Hibernate running and ran into following problem.

This is how one of my TDE schema look:

```
<tde:template xmlns:tde='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'
              xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
              xsi:schemaLocation='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'>
  <tde:context>/mytable</tde:context>
  <tde:enabled>true</tde:enabled>
  <tde:rows>
    <tde:row>
      <tde:schema-name>myschema</tde:schema-name>
      <tde:view-name>myview</tde:view-name>
      <tde:columns>
        <tde:column>
          <tde:name>mycolumn</tde:name>
          <tde:scalar-type>dateTime</tde:scalar-type>
          <tde:val>mycolumn</tde:val>
        </tde:column>
      </tde:columns>
    </tde:row>
  </tde:rows>
</tde:template>
```

Note that the column `mycolumn` is of type `dateTime`. Values look like this one: `2018-04-02T09:05:30`

The datetimes contain a 'T' and are as of `xs:dateTime('2018-04-02T09:05:30')` a valid xs:dateTime.

A select query (select mycolumn from mytable) successfully returns values from this table.

But as soon as i try to read values from this table using a PostgresSql Driver, this exception gets thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Trailing junk on timestamp: 'T09:05:30'
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.parseBackendTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:345) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.toTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:386) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getTimestamp(PgResultSet.java:610) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getTimestamp(PgResultSet.java:2513) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
```

I ran this problem down to the following [line](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/08631ccdabdb8ba6d52f398e2b0b46a9cf0cafbf/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils.java#L249), where Postgres finishes reading the date and only skips whitespaces, but not a 'T' character. So Postgres would happily accept a dateTime in the format `2018-04-02 09:05:30` without a 'T'. The problem is, marklogic doesnt. A missing 'T' in a dateTime sadly is not a valid dateTime in MarkLogic (check `xs:dateTime('2018-04-02 09:05:30')`).

This leads me to just one single solution, forking the Postgres Driver source and add code to skip that 'T' char.

Is there another solution i am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template value extractions support a limited number of XPath and transformation functions. See details on the template API [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_99178). When the template engine is indexing the views it can index transformations of the document values.

For your use-case you could configure the template view to replace the T in the dateTime with a space. The snippet below just replaces the `<tde:val>mycolumn</tde:val>` element in the template with `<tde:val>fn:replace(mycolumn, 'T', ' ')</tde:val>`. Since PostgreSQL requires date times formatted differently the MarkLogic dateTime you can index the column as a string by setting `<tde:scalar-type>string</tde:scalar-type>`. The `tde:node-data-extract` call should return a row with the string formatted for a PostgreSQL dateTime without the T.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $template := <tde:template xmlns:tde='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'
              xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
              xsi:schemaLocation='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde'>
  <tde:context>/mytable</tde:context>
  <tde:enabled>true</tde:enabled>
  <tde:rows>
    <tde:row>
      <tde:schema-name>myschema</tde:schema-name>
      <tde:view-name>myview</tde:view-name>
      <tde:columns>
        <tde:column>
          <tde:name>mycolumn</tde:name>
          <tde:scalar-type>string</tde:scalar-type>
          <tde:val>fn:replace(mycolumn, 'T', ' ')</tde:val>
        </tde:column>
      </tde:columns>
    </tde:row>
  </tde:rows>
</tde:template>

let $node-valid-date := <mytable><mycolumn>2018-04-02T09:05:30</mycolumn></mytable>

return tde:node-data-extract($node-valid-date, $template)
```

Comment: Just a minor missunderstanding:
Postgresql needs the data to not have a 'T'.

So my template would look like this:
        `<tde:column>
          <tde:name>mycolumn</tde:name>
          <tde:scalar-type>string</tde:scalar-type>
          <tde:val>fn:replace(mycolumn, 'T', ' ')</tde:val>
        </tde:column>
...
let $node-valid-date := <mytable><mycolumn>2018-04-02T09:05:30</mycolumn></mytable>
return tde:node-data-extract(($node-valid-date), $template)`

Comment: This only works with a scalar-type of `string`.
Surprisingly queries like `select day(mycolumn) from myview` do still work.
Do you know of any drawbacks this could have for like indexing or maybe others?

Comment: Using a `string` scalar-type seems to work for me so far without any other problems. Thanks alot for your comprehensive answer, again!

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding @maffelbaffel. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `Surprisingly queries like select day(mycolumn) from myview do still work.` This is because `day(mycolumn)` is executed on MarkLogic side, before Postgresql touches it, and it returns a string which cannot be misunderstood by Postgresql..

Comment: Not sure about drawbacks of using string over dateTime, probably none if you only use sql and odbc to query the data..